# JS Canvas - Save Transparent Image

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am using the following code for downloading (taking a snapshot) of a canvas:

```
    var strMime = "image/png";
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL(strMime);
    link.download = 'test1.png';
    link.click();
```

the thing is that it creates the "test1.png" image with a white background
(even if i set the canvas style background color to be transparent)

any idea how to generate transparent png files from canvas?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to

https://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/how-to-create-transparency-in-images-with-html5canvas

If you put a 24-bit PNG with alpha on the canvas it understands it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: didnt work, still downloading the image with white background

Comment: just a small remark: try calling `canvas.toDataURL()` without `strMime`

Comment: does it solved for you?